# PHP code working in PHP5, but not 4

Tags: php, syntax-error

This code of mine is working in PHP5, but not 4, and I have no clue why

```
function now(){
    return intval(
            explode(' ', microtime() )[1] // line 9
           ) * 100 
           +
           intval(
            explode(' ', microtime() )[0]
           * 100
           );
}
```

(The odd indentation was to help me see if I could find anything wrong.)

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /a/b/c on line 9
```

Anybody see anything?

Comment: What are you still using php 4 for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

php4 has no [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88). You can't do that `explode(' ', microtime() )[1]`.

You need to use temp variable.

```
function now(){
    $time = explode(' ', microtime() );
    return intval(
            $time[1] // line 9
           ) * 100 
           +
           intval(
            $time[0]
           * 100
           );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't index the return function of a value directly like that in older versions of PHP due to a bug in the parser that was only fixed deep into 5.x; you *must* use a temporary variable.

```
$foo = bar();
$baz = $foo[1];
```

Comment: It was not a bug. It was a php way.

Comment: @sectus: "We've always just done it this way" doesn't make it correct.

Comment: And "I think it should be done this way" doesn't make it a bug. The new feature was added in php5.4 for reference

Comment: [This feature was declined](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing)

Comment: @Clive: They didn't say "I think it should be done this way", they said "I would expect it to work this way".

Comment: Nope, I meant _you_ saying "I think it should work this way" doesn't make it a bug. Bugs happen when something doesn't work as it should. Function array dereferencing wasn't a feature before 5.4, so the lack of it can't possibly be a bug. But ill happily read any official literature you have to refute that